# How to check the progress of files moved from one place to another in terminal?

Tags: terminal

I am new to terminal. I started moving 30 gigs of data, from my desktop to my portable harddisk with the command `mv location1 location2`.

The problem is, I cannot see, how much data has been transferred.

How to see the progress in a bar format or in percentage format?

Answer (score 2):

I found this https://github.com/atdt/advcpmv it adds the -g option to cp and mv which will display a progress bar.

Here's how I got it to work on El Captain:

Requirements:

- Xcode
- wget (you can install wget with [brew](http://brew.sh/) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/))

Then:

```
wget http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.21.tar.xz
tar xvJf coreutils-8.21.tar.xz
cd coreutils-8.21/
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atdt/advcpmv/master/advcpmv-0.5-8.21.patch
patch -p1 -i advcpmv-0.5-8.21.patch
./configure
make
```

At this point you will have *cp* and *mv* binaries in src/ give them a try and if you don't have problem with them you can move them to `/usr/local/bin`.

You may also rename the two binaries to *cpgres* and *mvgres* (or other unique names) so that you can use the standard cp/mv commands also.

Comment: @klanomath You are wrong, I just tried and it works fine. Thanks for downvoting without trying. So I will the answer with the steps.

Comment: I downvoted the answer because it was almost a link-only answer. But I also upvote answer after they got improved ;-)!

Answer (score 1):

**rsync** can do that for you, with a nice progress meter that (as the man page says) "gives a bored user something to watch".

```
rsync --progress --remove-source-files {source file} {destination}
```

There's a lot else that rsync can do, such as mirroring directories, recursing large trees, throttling bandwidth usage, and much more. **man rsync** is your friend.

Oh, and since you're moving a directory tree, be sure to include the **--recursive** option.

Comment: it does not give a progress meter for the whole set of files.it shows for each specific file.
which is just occupying terminal space, no actual knowledge is achieved from it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard `mv` command doesn't offer an option to show progress. What you can do instead is

- open a new Terminal tab with <kbd>Cmd-T</kbd>
- check the size of the target file by running `ls -l location2`